# Attach sfDoctrineActAsTaggablePlugin to objects

Tags: tags, doctrine, symfony-1.4

I have successfully managed to install sfDoctrineActAsTaggablePlugin, added the Taggable behavior to the model I want to be taggable in schema.yml and rebuilt all models. Can someone point me to a tutorial that shows how to attach the tags to an object and retrieve the objects tags? I am not sure where to go from here. I am looking for a very simple solution. Something that allows me add tags separated by commas and retrieve them. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As defined in the [README file](https://github.com/annismckenzie/sfDoctrineActAsTaggablePlugin/blob/master/README#L65), it's as easy as this:

Consider a Doctrine "Post" class:

```php
$post = new Post();
$post->addTag('toto');
$post->addTag('tata, tutu');
$post->addTag(array('Titi', 'Gros Minet'));
$post->save();
```

The plugin supports [machine tags](http://www.flickr.com/groups/api/discuss/72157594497877875/):

```php
$post = new Post();
$post->addTag('iso:isbn=123456789');
$post->save();

// assume City is a taggable class
$city = new City();
$city->addTag('geo:lat=47.3456');
$city->save();
```

Comment: merci j0k. sans tes conseils, je suis un petit peu perdu. this definitely helps me understand how the plugin works, but I still have no idea on how to add a tag field to be populated by user in my forms. can you help me with that?

Comment: Check line `The Tag Widget Renderer` in the doc, you have a component that does exactly this job.